# Entity Framework Core Migration Seed throw Duplication Error

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, database-migration, seeding, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working with .NET 6 and an Entity Framework 7 solution. Part of migration, I have created a `Seed` extension classes to insert the data. My primary keys are of type Guid that I am inserting with object to insert. Once of my class has about 70 seed data and I am constantly getting `duplication error` on different Ids where I double check there is no duplicate of Guid Id.

I come across `migrationBuilder.UpdateData()` but not sure if is right? And second how to apply within my code?

The `Add-Migration [xx]` works fine, error is thrown when running `update-database`.

I have notice after Add-Migration, the migration class insert data of same object into 2 part with split of record but duplicate one of the record that throws the error

```
 migrationBuilder.InsertData(
            schema: "dbo",
            table: "DataReadingRule",
            columns: new[] { "DataReadingRuleId", "EndFieldTo", "FieldName", "FieldTxtJustity", "FieldWidth", "ImportFileDefinationId", "IsRequire", "Multiplier", "Notes", "RowIndex", "StartFieldFrom", "TableTitle", "TxtFieldFormat" },
            values: new object[,]
            {
```

This is the error:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_DataReadingRule'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DataReadingRule'. The duplicate key value is (xxxxxxxx-7730-4da0-b987-439a81bxxxxx).
> The statement has been terminated.

Entity class:

```
public class DataReadingRule
{
    public Guid DataReadingRuleId { get; set; }
    public Guid ImportFileDefinationId { get; set; }
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
    public string TableTitle { get; set; } 
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public DataRequire IsRequire { get; set; }
    public int FieldWidth { get; set; }
    public int StartFieldFrom { get; set; }
    public int EndFieldTo { get; set; }
    public TxtJustity FieldTxtJustity { get; set; }
    public TextFieldFormat TxtFieldFormat { get; set; }
    public int Multiplier { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; } 
    public ImportFileDefination ImportFileDefination { get; set; }
    public DataMappingRule DataMappingRule { get; set; }
}
```

Seed extension method:

```
public static class DataReadingRuleSeed
{
    public static void Seed(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DataReadingRule>()
            .HasData(
                new DataReadingRule { DataReadingRuleId = Guid.Parse("xxxxxxxx-7730-4da0-b987-439a81bf9xxx"), ImportFileDefinationId = Guid.Parse("xxxxxxxx-18f6-48df-aac6-f248952xxxxx"), RowIndex = 1, TableTitle = "", FieldName = "", IsRequire = DataRequire.Optional, FieldWidth = 0, StartFieldFrom = 0, EndFieldTo = 0, FieldTxtJustity = TxtJustity.NotProvided, TxtFieldFormat = TextFieldFormat.NotProvided, Multiplier = 0, Notes = "" },
 .....
    );
  }
}
```

`DbContext` class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     DataReadingRuleSeed.Seed(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: is the `DataReadingRuleId` has to be hardcoded? you can use [`Guid.NewGuid()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-6.0) to obtain new randomized guid.

Comment: No it doesn't have to be but because there are `foreign keys` involve in seeding data hence is easier to hard coded, however duplication happened in generated migration class under migrationBuilder.InsertData where it created twice for the same class `table: "DataReadingRule` and duplicated one of the record

Comment: How many migrations do you have? I suspect that at the time of adding new migration, your database state is not consistent with the migration state, which causing the seed data to be inserted twice.

Comment: @K.Z you can always put the guids in variables somewhere. also, neverever is right, you could just nuke the entire table and redo the migration. at least we can be sure whether the problem is the code or the database.